# MongoDB: Update nested element

Tags: mongodb

I want to update this document...

```
{
    "_id" : "2QCTWXJHMa3Sjnta5",
    "text" : [
        {
            "id" : "krD8yXFEEd8Esc4Qc",
            "sentence" : "dasdsada."
        },
        {
            "id" : "AwXHZmPKSPyKvd9E9",
            "sentence" : "adsdadas ."
        },
        {
            "id" : "bsf6RyKDQyrnqsmK7",
            "sentence" : "daadadadad"
        }
    ]
}
```

... to this

```
{
    "_id" : "2QCTWXJHMa3Sjnta5",
    "text" : [
        {
            "id" : "krD8yXFEEd8Esc4Qc",
            "sentence" : "dasdsada."
        },
        {
            "id" : "AwXHZmPKSPyKvd9E9",
            "sentence" : "Just changed"
        },
        {
            "id" : "bsf6RyKDQyrnqsmK7",
            "sentence" : "daadadadad"
        }
    ]
}
```

Therefore I tried:

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: '2QCTWXJHMa3Sjnta5', text.id: 'AwXHZmPKSPyKvd9E9' },
    { $set: { sentence: "Just changed" }}

);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify an element in an array in order to update it. You can do it with the positional [$ operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Be aware that positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element in array that matches the query. So you can update only the first matched element in array with it.

Try the following query:

```
Collection.update(
  { _id: '2QCTWXJHMa3Sjnta5', 'text.id': 'AwXHZmPKSPyKvd9E9' },
  { $set: { 'text.$.sentence': "Just changed" }}

);
```